# setInterval in react does not update the setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, use-state

I want to make a countdown timer (25 minutes). This is the code in App.js file

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(1500);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [minute, setMinute] = useState(remainingTime/60);

  function timer() {
    setRemainingTime(remainingTime-1);
    let newMinute = remainingTime/60;
    let minuteArray = [...newMinute.toString()];
    setMinute(parseInt(minuteArray.slice(0,2).join("")));
    setSeconds(remainingTime%60);
    console.log(minute);
    console.log(seconds);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="pomodoro">
        <div className="timer">{minute}:{seconds}</div>
        <div className="button-container">
          <button className="start" onClick={() => setInterval(timer, 1000)}>start</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The interval does not update the state value. The minute value always 25 and the seconds value always 0. When I don't use setInterval and just use the timer function like this

```
<button className="start" onClick={timer}>start</button>
```

every time I click the start button, the value changes. Any idea? I know I should use clearInterval too but I don't know where to put it. Should I create a new function which contain setInterval and clearInterval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

**The main issue is stale enclosures of state in the `timer` callback.**

Within the interval callback, the standard form of setting a new value doesn't work because the callback keeps using the same (non-updated) state value each time it runs:

***—this doesn't work:***   `setValue(value + 1)`

## Solution

Use the alternate form of setting new value:

***—this will work:*** `setValue((value) => value + 1)`

This form allows the callback to obtain a fresh value with the most recent state every time it runs.

## Details

1. The `minute` and `seconds` is considered derived state (from `remainingTime`) so it shouldn't also be stored in state, it is easily computed from state.
2. Use a functional state update to update the `remainingTime` state from the previous state, not the state of the render cycle the callback was enqueued in.
3. Use a React ref to hold an interval timer ref, so the interval can be cleared.
4. Use an `useEffect` hook to return a clean up function to clear any running intervals when the component unmounts.

Code:

```
function App() {
  const timerRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }, []);

  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = React.useState(1500);

  function timer() {
    setRemainingTime((remainingTime) => remainingTime - 1);
  }

  const startTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);             // clear any running interval
    setRemainingTime(1500);                      // reset state back to 25 minutes
    timerRef.current = setInterval(timer, 1000); // start/restart interval
  };

  const minute = String(Math.floor(remainingTime / 60)).padStart(2, 0);
  const seconds = String(remainingTime % 60).padStart(2, 0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="pomodoro">
        <div className="timer">
          {minute}:{seconds}
        </div>
        <div className="button-container">
          <button className="start" onClick={startTimer}>
            start
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image]

[image: Edit setinterval-in-react-does-not-update-the-setstate]

Since this will likely be a follow-up question, use another `useEffect` to "listen" to the `remainingTime` state and when the time hits 0, clear the interval, reset `remainingTime` back 1500 (*for display*), and show any alarm or alert or whatever for the pomodoro break/schedule.

Answer (score 1):

On every rerender, timer is set as 1500. Use closure here, activated on click.

```
function timer() {
    let t = remainingTime;
    setInterval(() => {
      t -= 1;
      setRemainingTime(t);
      let newMinute = t / 60;
      let minuteArray = [...newMinute.toString()];
      setMinute(parseInt(minuteArray.slice(0, 2).join("")));
      setSeconds(t % 60);
      console.log(minute);
      console.log(seconds);
    }, 1000); }
```